# A cyclist rides from Alberville to Bakersville

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A cyclist rides from Albertville to Bakersville, a distance of 120 km. His return trip takes 1 hour longer, because his speed decreases by 10 km/hr. **How fast does he ride each way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance travelled is the velocity times the time he took to get it there. This translates to $120 = vt$ with appropriate units. When he's moving back **the distance stays the same**.

However, his speed decreases by 10 units and his time increases by one unit. This means $120 = (v-10)(t+1)$.

This is a headstart.

Comment: Thanks! I am given 5 pairs of answers. I should subtitute them into equation and check it or there is rational way to solve it? May be by the set of equations?

Comment: There is a rational way, which is solving the system of equations and finding the appropriate value for $v$.

Comment: Thanks! Got the right answer and understood